# Group by Month and Gender in Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following queryset, It works well with the *grouping by month*.

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(date_created__year='2018')\
           .annotate(date=TruncMonth('date_created'))\
           .values('date').annotate(total_entries=Count('id'))
```

What I want is to group also by **gender**, here is a similar model with the `gender` field

```
class UserProfile:
    date_created = models.DateTime(auto_now_add=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=[('F',"Female"),('M',"Male")],default='M')
```

Expecting result:

```
May: 5 users [4(Male), 1(Female)]
June: 20 users [15(Male), 5(Female)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `django < 2.0` you can use [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) and `Sum()` to annotate the values you want:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Case, When
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(date_created__year='2018').annotate(
    date=TruncMonth('date_created'),
).values('date').annotate(
    total_entries=Count('id'),
    total_male=Sum(Case(When(gender='M', then=1), default=0, output_field=models.IntegerField())),
    total_female=Sum(Case(When(gender='F', then=1), default=0, output_field=models.IntegerField())),
)
```

Since `django 2.0` you can use [Conditional Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(date_created__year='2018').annotate(
        date=TruncMonth('date_created'),
    ).values('date').annotate(
        total_entries=Count('id'),
        total_male=Count('id', filter=Q(gender='M')),
        total_female=Count('id', filter=Q(gender='F')),
)
```

Comment: Awesome! your second option displays the same result for `total_entries, total_male, total_female`, maybe because I don't use django >= 2.0. But the first works well